# How to make Hasura's permissions feature work when two tables are involved?

Tags: permissions, graphql, hasura

Using Hasura GraphQL Engine, given the following diagram:

[image]

How can I restrict the **select** action on table `company` to just allow select the company record that is associated(fk) with user on table `user`?

I'm using the **x-hasura-user-id** session variable, of course. But how to refer the 'current' `company_id` while looking into `user` table?

This is a simple question, but knowing this, I'll be able to make more complex validations in the future.

Comment: Permission rules can span relationship tables: https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/auth/authorization/permission-rules.html#using-relationships-or-nested-objects

Comment: Nice, i was using X-Hasura-Default-Role with X-Hasura-User-Id session variables, i needed to change to X-Hasura-Role and now it works perfectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I made it.

I was using the `X-Hasura-User-Id` with `X-Hasura-Default-Role` session variables, then every request were returning all the records, and that's not what I was trying to do. After some hours of research I found that I need to use `X-Hasura-Role` instead of `X-Hasura-Default-Role`.

This solved my issue, hope it'll be useful for someone with the same problem.

Comment: You really saved my day. To me, this looks like a bug in Hasura. How did you find that?

Comment: @dknaus I have no idea dude, now it is on the docs, but back then I just had some enlightenment from God.